# <p> tag inside listview autoset text in jquery mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am using listview of **jquery mobile version 1.4.5**. I want to make `<p>` inside `<li>` to make description text auto set according to the width but right now it doesn't make it auto set instead it adds ellipsis.

Here is a code:

```
<ul id="comment" class="touch" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="a" data-divider-theme="a" data-icon="false"> <li data-role="list-divider">Monday, October 11, 2010 <span class="ui-li-count" style="margin-top: -2px; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;">5 stars</span></li> <li><a id="" href="" style=""> <img id="" src="/img.jpg" style="width:66px; height:66px; border: solid 2px #DCDCDC; outline:none; margin: 9px 7px; border-radius: 50%;" /> <h2 id="" onclick="">Testing</h2> <p style="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque non efficitur lorem. Phasellus efficitur, metus sit amet mattis ultrices, est est convallis leo, nec finibus quam nulla nec felis. Curabitur eleifend dolor elit, at finibus odio semper quis. Curabitur consectetur odio sit amet nulla varius cursus. Nullam ut nunc in neque dapibus aliquam vel quis risus. Nunc vitae odio eu ligula sagittis lacinia. Mauris id odio at enim lacinia gravida. Aenean ac sem vitae lorem aliquam gravida.</p> <span id="" class="ui-li-count"></span> </a> </li> </ul>
```

I tried to make height of the `<li>` and `<a>` as auto and even i and it 1000px to test it but nothing works.

The jquery mobile `<li>` css code:

```
.ui-listview>li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
}
.ui-listview, .ui-listview>li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
user agent stylesheet
li {
    display: list-item;
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}
.ui-listview, .ui-listview>li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
user agent stylesheet
ul, menu, dir {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}
.ui-overlay-a, .ui-page-theme-a, .ui-page-theme-a .ui-panel-wrapper {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border-color: #bbb;
    color: #333;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #f3f3f3;
}
.ui-overlay-a, .ui-page-theme-a, .ui-page-theme-a .ui-panel-wrapper {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border-color: #bbb;
    color: #333;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #f3f3f3;
}
```

`<a>` code:

```
.ui-page-theme-a .ui-btn, html .ui-bar-a .ui-btn, html .ui-body-a .ui-btn, html body .ui-group-theme-a .ui-btn, html head+body .ui-btn.ui-btn-a, .ui-page-theme-a .ui-btn:visited, html .ui-bar-a .ui-btn:visited, html .ui-body-a .ui-btn:visited, html body .ui-group-theme-a .ui-btn:visited, html head+body .ui-btn.ui-btn-a:visited {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    border-color: #ddd;
    color: #333;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #f3f3f3;
}
.ui-listview>.ui-li-has-thumb>.ui-btn, .ui-listview>.ui-li-static.ui-li-has-thumb {
    min-height: 3.625em;
    padding-left: 6.25em;
}
.ui-listview>.ui-li-has-count>.ui-btn, .ui-listview>.ui-li-static.ui-li-has-count, .ui-listview>.ui-li-divider.ui-li-has-count {
    padding-right: 2.8125em;
}
.ui-page-theme-a a:visited, html .ui-bar-a a:visited, html .ui-body-a a:visited, html body .ui-group-theme-a a:visited {
    color: #38c;
}
.ui-listview-inset>.ui-li-static, .ui-listview-inset>.ui-li-divider, .ui-listview-inset>li>a.ui-btn {
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
}
.ui-listview>.ui-li-static, .ui-listview>.ui-li-divider, .ui-listview>li>a.ui-btn {
    border-width: 1px 0 0;
    border-style: solid;
}
.ui-listview>.ui-li-static, .ui-listview>.ui-li-divider, .ui-listview>li>a.ui-btn {
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.ui-page-theme-a a, html .ui-bar-a a, html .ui-body-a a, html body .ui-group-theme-a a {
    color: #38c;
    font-weight: 700;
}
a:-webkit-any-link {
    color: -webkit-link;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: auto;
}
.ui-listview, .ui-listview>li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
li {
    display: list-item;
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}
.ui-listview, .ui-listview>li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
ul, menu, dir {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}
.ui-overlay-a, .ui-page-theme-a, .ui-page-theme-a .ui-panel-wrapper {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border-color: #bbb;
    color: #333;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #f3f3f3;
}
.ui-overlay-a, .ui-page-theme-a, .ui-page-theme-a .ui-panel-wrapper {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border-color: #bbb;
    color: #333;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #f3f3f3;
}
```

Comment: can you show your css code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the white-space css atrribute of the `<p>` tag to normal:

```
<p class="wrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...

.wrap {
  white-space: normal !important;
}
```

## **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/cqukt/)**